# Plugging laptop into power outlet makes the desktop make noise

Tags: desktop-computer

We have a desktop computer. It has recently had some issues. Speakers randomly make noise even if nothing is working. Now a new symptom has arisen. When desktop is working and i plug in my laptop charger to the same power outlet where the desktop is, then desktop makes that windows noise when you plug some USB stick or something into the computer.

It seems like something is causing electrical interference in the computer. The soundcard itself has previously had problems with mouse. With a previous mouse, when mouse scroll was used there was a noise in speakers. New mouse fixed that issue and for a while everyhing was ok until these recent events.

Does anyone have any idea what can cause this? Im worried that there might be a serious issue with the desktop.

My 1 theory is that the case gets a small charge somewhere, and when plugging in something the fields change and this causes interference. But the windows noise makes it seems like the computer thinks something was plugged in, but nothing was.

Comment: Make sure the power bar has been properly ground to the circuit you plugged it into. Proper grounds normally prevent static from that source

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like two different issues.

This first part is probably just the speaker wire acting as an antenna for EM interference from the computer system (scrolling is probably GPU, but old CRT monitors used to do this also). Unshielded speaker wires also pick up cell phone negotiation.

Regarding the windows tone when plugging in the laptop: perhaps the power is sagging at the wall outlet. One might expect the system to just shut down, but it will depend on the device.

You might try looking at your motherboard ad gpu for swelling capacitors